# combine 2 array with same key into 1 array

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

I have 2 Array:

```
$arr1 = Array (
         [2] => Array ( [0] => 41000 [1] => 31079 ) 
         [3] => Array ( [0] => 42963 [1] => 41189 ) 
    )

$arr2 = Array ( 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 40213 [1] => 42054 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 42998 [1] => 34567 ) 
    )
```

I want to combine these two arrays to this array with same key:

```
$arr3 = Array ( 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 40213 [1] => 42054 [2] => 41000 [3] => 31079 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 42998 [1] => 34567 [2] => 42963 [3] => 41189 ) 
    )
```

I tried almost anything (merge, combine, join) but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your values look more like JSON - are these decoded before you use them, adding an example of what you have tried can help clarify what exactly you start with.

Comment: my bad wrong formatted on this post, thanks..

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your formatting, the problem was the description. You didn't have arrays, you had JSON strings. We like to be precise here... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nice and easy thing to do.

```
$arr1 = [2 => [0 => 41000, 1 => 31079], 3 => [0 => 42963, 1 => 41189]];
$arr2 = [2 => [0 => 40213, 1 => 42054], 3 => [0 => 42998, 1 => 34567]];

function addArray(&$bucket, $water)
{
    foreach ($water as $key => $drop) {
        $bucket[$key] = array_merge($bucket[$key] ?? [], $drop);
    }
}

$combined = [];
addArray($combined, $arr1);
addArray($combined, $arr2);

var_export($combined);
```

See [a PHP fiddle here](https://3v4l.org/s4JXj).

The output is:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 41000,
    1 => 31079,
    2 => 40213,
    3 => 42054,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 42963,
    1 => 41189,
    2 => 42998,
    3 => 34567,
  ),
)
```

How does it work? I wrote a little function that would add the input arrays to an array that combines all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $arr1 = array(
        2 => array(41000, 31079),
        3 => array(42963, 41189)
    );

    $arr2 = array(
        2 => array(40213, 42054),
        3 => array(42998, 34567)
    );

    $arr3 = array();

    foreach($arr1 as $key => $values){
        if(!isset($arr3[$key])){
            $arr3[$key] = array();
        }
        $arr3[$key] = array_merge($arr3[$key], $values);
    }

    foreach($arr2 as $key => $values){
        if(!isset($arr3[$key])){
            $arr3[$key] = array();
        }
        $arr3[$key] = array_merge($arr3[$key], $values);
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr3);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 41000
            [1] => 31079
            [2] => 40213
            [3] => 42054
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42963
            [1] => 41189
            [2] => 42998
            [3] => 34567
        )

)
```